# How is an "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module" error overcome in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Quite recently I was following directions about working with NodeJS when I came across an error that I usually don't encounter.

The error message was ***"Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module [module-name]"***.

To reach this error, I had run **"npm install -g firebase-tools"**, **"firebase init"** and **"firebase deploy"**, and within an index.js file there were two "const" calls with 'require'.

I was sure that somehow I had learnt the way around this error before, hence why I had never encountered it before, so I went back to see a previous source of guidance and then it occurred to me what I should try.

You may have encountered this error before, do you know how to resolve it please?

Answer (score 0):

What I came to understand was that the **module-name** was the equivalent of a package that had to be installed, and in fact, there were two such packages that needed to be installed in my case.

I found that in my case, the *"npm install -g firebase-tools"* was an insufficient call because the two 'required' packages were not installed, and that that was why the error arose.

So, as well as the "npm install -g firebase-tools" call within the terminal at the project's root directory, it was also necessary for me to change directory, into the 'functions' directory, and then call ***"npm install module-name1 module-name2"*** in order to install the required packages there.

It worked.  After doing this the error did not arise again.  Perfect!

Solution

```css
cd functions
npm install module-name1 module-name2
```